# I am looking for a touch screen laptop that works awesome with Ubuntu ( it has to be a Full laptop NOT NETBOOK)

Tags: hardware, laptop

I am looking for a nicely priced touchscreen laptop (not netbook) that works great with Ubuntu. can you help me out?
 -Thanks!!-

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [X61 Tablet with touch screen built-in](http://www.tabletpcreview.com/default.asp?newsID=868). Touchscreen should work out of the box on Ubuntu. I have an X61 Tablet with no touch screen support, and I just love it and its quality.

Comment: Not bad! looks old but nice size !

Answer (score 1):

Buy an [iPed](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/05/31/iped_irobot/) from China. It runs Linux with the touchscreen support. Plus, it is not just "nicely priced," but has an extremely reasonable price tag: $105.

Comment: thats a good start but not a laptop. and i do not want anything that even sounds like a apple product .

Answer (score 1):

I use Ubuntu in a HP Pavilion tx2500 it works great. 
Since Lucid touch screen and pen works out of the box. And you can rotate the screen to use it as a tablet.
No drivers problems, wifi works, camera works. Using it with Ubuntu since Feb/2008

Comment: Vary good choice thank you I ended up with the HP TouhSmart tm2 with a few upgrades, and the pin does work well ! but the right click on the pin does not and the screen flip feature also does not